# How can I make the tilde operator change ‘==’ to ‘!=’ in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like the normal-mode command tilde `~`, in addition to changing the case of letters, to also be able to change the text `==` to `!=` and `!=` to `==`.

I find that I do this quite often and I'd like a shortcut that still uses the tilde.

Comment: @Kent, answering your own questions is [explicitly encouraged on SO](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). On this one I do find the question a bit odd, though, since it isn't really shorter that using `r` anyway.

Comment: @cms_mgr I almost always accidentally hit `~` instead of r! when I'm changing from != to == and it bugged the heck out of me. I wanted to document what I did here since Stack Overflow is great for little examples like this.

Comment: Fwiw, this question is confusing from the start as you worded it. You're talking about the ~ *normal mode command*, not an operator, whereas you're asking about changing `==` et al, which *are* operators. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do in vimscript.
Add the following to your `.vimrc` or `source` this code from a different file.

```
" ----------------------
"  Tilde switches ==/!=
" ----------------------
function! TildeSwitch()
  " Gets the pair of characters under the cursor, before and behind.
  let cur_pair = getline(".")[col(".") - 2 : col(".") - 1]
  let next_pair = getline(".")[col(".") - 1 : col(".")]

  if cur_pair == "=="
    normal! "_ch!
    normal! l
  elseif next_pair == "=="
    normal! r!
  elseif cur_pair == "!="
    normal! "_ch=
    normal! l
  elseif next_pair == "!="
    normal! r=
  else
    " If == and != are not found, simply use the regular tilde.
    normal! ~
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> ~ :silent call TildeSwitch()<cr>
```

Comment: What is `"_` before `ch!`, isn't that register filled automatically anyway when doing a change?

Comment: `"_` is the black-hole register (`_`). I use that register there so that the 'last used' `"` register is unchanged.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_

Answer (score 3):

Toggling between two alternatives (like `==` and `!=`) is only a special case of toggling between multiple options. I'd advise against overloading the binary `~` command and instead use `<C-A>` / `<C-X>`. The [SwapIt - Extensible keyword swapper plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2294) offers this and actually has a default option to toggle `==`, `!=`, `<=`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let me propose an alternative implementation of this extended `~` command:

```
nnoremap <silent> ~ :call SwitchNeq()<cr>~

function! SwitchNeq()
    let [s, c] = [@/, getpos('.')]
    s/[!=]\ze\%#=\|\%#[!=]\ze=/\='!='[submatch(0)=='!']/e
    let @/ = s
    call setpos('.', c)
endfunction
```

Comment: Could you add some comments explaining how that works? Or maybe just explain the thinking?